# Page curl on top right corner of UIView / UIViewController

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiviewcontroller, page-curl

I am looking to do a partial page curl (but will settle for a full page curl) that starts in the top right corner.

I have managed to do this successfully using:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:1.0];
CAMediaTimingFunction *fun=[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[animation setTimingFunction:fun];
animation.type = @"pageCurl";
animation.subtype=@"fromRight";
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.endProgress = 0.75;
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[[bckground layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pageCurlAnimation"];
```

But as this uses a Private API- I can't risk being rejected when submitting my app.

Anyone know how I can get either `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp` or `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` working from the top right corner?

Comment: Also, you can change the `subtype` into constant `kCATransitionFromRight`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no private API in your code. I have the same code in an app which was successfully submitted to the appstore.

Private API means using undocumented methods. Undocumented string values are okey.